# "Your idea's sounding great" or "Your idea sounds great"

Tags: differences

What is the difference in meaning between the following two sentences?

> (1) Your idea's sounding great.
>
> (2) Your idea sounds great.

To me, as a non-native speaker both sound grammatical, with the second one being more general. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical. The implication of 'sounding' is that the idea appears good so far, and requires expansion.

Comment: I think the primary implication is the speaker only knows (non-mainstream) "Indian English".